# Improving moving-window computation in memory consumption and speed

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is it possible to obtain better performance (both in memory consumption and speed) in this moving-window computation? I have a `1000x1000` numpy array and I take `16x16` windows through the whole array and finally apply some function to each window (in this case, a discrete cosine transform.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

X = np.arange(1000*1000, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1000,1000)
window_size = 16
windows = view_as_windows(X, (window_size,window_size))
dcts = np.zeros(windows.reshape(-1,window_size, window_size).shape, dtype=np.float32)
for idx, window in enumerate(windows.reshape(-1,window_size, window_size)):
    dcts[idx, :, :] = dct(window)
dcts = dcts.reshape(windows.shape)
```

This code takes too much memory (in the example above, the memory consumption is not so bad -  `windows` uses 1Gb and `dcts` also needs 1Gb) and is taking 25 seconds to complete. I'm a bit unsure as to what I'm doing wrong because this should be a straightforward calculation (e.g. filtering an image.) Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

I was initially worried that the arrays produced by Kington's solution and my initial approach were very different, but the difference is restricted to the boundaries, so it is unlikely to cause serious issues for most applications. The only remaining problem is that both solutions are very slow. Currently, the first solution takes 1min 10s and the second solution 59 seconds.

**UPDATE 2:**

I noticed the biggest culprits by far are `dct` and `np.mean`. Even `generic_filter` performs decently (8.6 seconds) using a "cythonized" version of `mean` with bottleneck:

```
import bottleneck as bp
def func(window, shape):
    window = window.reshape(shape)
    #return np.abs(dct(dct(window, axis=1), axis=0)).mean()
    return bp.nanmean(dct(window))

result = scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(X, func, (16, 16),
                                      extra_arguments=([16, 16],))
```

I'm currently reading how to wrap C code using numpy in order to replace `scipy.fftpack.dct`. If anyone knows how to do it, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you really need to store the full, overlapping intermediate results? (`dcts`)  Usually, you're only interested in a single output value for each "window" when filtering an image (e.g. `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`).

Comment: That is a very good point. Right now I'm using the mean of the dcts. Something like this: `dcts.reshape(windows.shape).mean(axis=2).mean(axis=2)` I will take a look at `generic_filter`

Comment: If you just store the mean, it should speed things up and dramatically reduce the memory usage.  `windows` actually only uses the memory of the original `X` array.  You're creating a huge array with `dcts`, though.

Comment: Correct.That is the problem. I'm trying to see how generic_filter works in order to give it a try.

Comment: The results are identical, actually. However, your original code simply ignores the boundaries and discards data near them.  The first result from `generic_filter` is at [0,0] of your input array, while the first result from your original solution would be at [8, 8].

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the differences in the boundary, although I suppose that for most applications those small discrepancies won't be an issue. The only problem is that it takes 59 seconds to run the code. Unfortunately, there is no much room for improvement using Cython and I assume `generic_filter` is coded in C, right?

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of overhead in a python function call.  You _can_ speed it up a lot by using cython or C, but you'll need to avoid calling any python functions inside the inner loop.

Comment: I think that implies removing `view_as_windows`. Maybe even a double loop using Cython would be faster. In any case, I need to use dct inside the loop, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `scipy.fftpack.dct` calculates separate transforms along the last axis of the input array, you can replace your loop with:

```
windows = view_as_windows(X, (window_size,window_size))
dcts = dct(windows)
result1 = dcts.mean(axis=(2,3))
```

Now only the `dcts` array requires a lot of memory and `windows` remains merely a view into `X`. And because the DCT's are calculated with a single function call it's also much faster. However, because the windows overlap there are lots of repeated calculations. This can be overcome by only calculating the DCT for each sub-row once, followed by a windowed mean:

```
ws = window_size
row_dcts = dct(view_as_windows(X, (1, ws)))
cs = row_dcts.squeeze().sum(axis=-1).cumsum(axis=0)
result2 = np.vstack((cs[ws-1], cs[ws:]-cs[:-ws])) / ws**2
```

Though it seems what is gained in effeciency is lost in code clarity... But basically the approach here is to first calculate the DCT's and then take the window average by summing over the 2D window and then dividing by the number of elements in the window. The DCTs are already calculated over rowwise moving windows, so we take a regular sum over those windows. However we need to take a moving window sum over the columns, to arrive at the proper 2D window sums. To do this efficiently we use a `cumsum` trick, where:

```
sum(A[p:q])  # q-p == window_size
```

Is equivalent to:

```
cs = cumsum(A)
cs[q-1] - cs[p-1]
```

This avoids having to sum the exact same numbers over and over. Unfortunately it doesn't work for the first window (when `p == 0`), so for that we have to take only `cs[q-1]` and stack it together with the other window sums. Finally we divide by the number of elements to arrive at the 2D window average.

If you like to do a 2D DCT than this second approach becomes less interesting, beause you'll eventually need the full `985 x 985 x 16 x 16` array before you can take the mean.

---

Both approaches above should be equivalent, but it may be a good idea to perform the arithmetic with 64-bit floats:

```
np.allclose(result1, result2, atol=1e-6)
# False
np.allclose(result1, result2, atol=1e-5)
# True
```

Comment: This is very clever. I can't believe I didn't realize I could `dct` each window simply using `dct(windows)`. As you said, the problem is the memory in your first example which, by the way, is extremely fast. The second snippet works fine, although I don't understand the `cumsum` part and the last line is also a bit cryptic to me. Can you elaborate on those parts? The thing I noticed is that by using `(1, ws)` windows, I can't process on the vertical as I want in an image (e.g. applying a 2d DCT (`dct(dct(X, axis=1), axis=0)`). Is it possible to extend it to cover 2d filtering/processing?

Comment: @RobertSmith I've made some edits and hope it's a bit clearer now. Unfortunately for the windowed 2D DCT I think you're out of luck, because approaches either are slow, take a lot of memory or are awkward to implement efficiently.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks! As for the 2D DCT, that's what I thought. Since your answer is very close that what I initially asked, I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

`skimage.util.view_as_windows` is using striding tricks to make an array of overlapping "windows" that doesn't use any additional memory.

However, when you make a new array of the shape shape, it will require ~32 times (16 x 16) the memory that your original `X` array or the `windows` array used.

Based on your comment, your end result is doing `dcts.reshape(windows.shape).mean(axis=2).mean(axis=2)` - taking the mean of the `dct` of each window.

Therefore, it would be more memory-efficient (though similar performance wise) to take the mean inside the loop and not store the huge intermediate array of windows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

X = np.arange(1000*1000, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1000,1000)
window_size = 16
windows = view_as_windows(X, (window_size, window_size))
dcts = np.zeros(windows.shape[:2], dtype=np.float32).ravel()
for idx, window in enumerate(windows.reshape(-1, window_size, window_size)):
    dcts[idx] = dct(window).mean()
dcts = dcts.reshape(windows.shape[:2])
```

---

Another option is `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`.  It won't increase performance much (the bottleneck is the python function call in the inner loop), but you'll have a lot more boundary condition options, and it will be fairly memory efficient:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct
import scipy.ndimage

X = np.arange(1000*1000, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1000,1000)

def func(window, shape):
    window = window.reshape(shape)
    return dct(window).mean()

result = scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(X, func, (16, 16),
                                      extra_arguments=([16, 16],))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling a bit trying to figure out why I don't get the same result using this method. Maybe, the mode argument has something to do?

Comment: @RobertSmith - Yes, the boundary conditions (`mode` kwarg) are different and the shape of the returned array (1000x1000) are both different. The method you were using doesn't do the calculation on the full image, so there are not boundaries. `generic_filter` does the calculation on the entire image, so it has to handle boundary conditions in some way.  The default is to pad with zeros.  `mode='reflect'` or `'wrap'` might make more sense for this case.

Comment: I see. The problem is that `wrap`or `reflect` are passing very different arrays than what I had. This, of course, assuming I'm interpreting the arrays correctly. Let me update with more details. Hopefully, a rearrangement is enough to get similar results.

Comment: By the way, your first solution obviously is a good way to keep the memory down, but it takes quite a bit more of time to complete, presumably because performing operations to each window is more costly than calculating such operations once at the end.